# Alternative to Objective HTML Google Map plugin

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps, objective-html

I have a site that’s currently using [Objective HTML’s Google Maps plugin](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps) to import entries and add geolocation. It looks like the plugin is no longer being actively developed or supported so I’m looking into alternative options.

There are [some good Google Map alternatives](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gmaps) on Devot-ee, but as far as I can tell, nothing I found can handle importing as well. I'm curious if anyone has an alternative solution for supporting this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The best alternative I've found is the excellent [Gmaps](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gmaps) plugin from Rein de Vries.

You can pair this plugin with his [Gmaps Importer plugin](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gmaps-importer) (which is actually an extension of [DataGrab](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab)) to replicate the importing functionality of the Objective HTML version.